# Problemas usando transiciones para navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, materialize

Tengo un navbar que está en el medio de una página pero, al pulsar un botón que pertenece al navbar, quiero que se vaya arriba como un `position: fixed` top, pero con una transición o parecido a animate de jQuery.

Ya he probado de todo y nada, pero el nav se va arriba sin ningún tipo de transición o algo parecido al animate de jQuery. Lo que he estado usando es materialize con jquery.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo con jQuery o por CSS?

Éste es mi código (para ver el problema hay que pulsar en el botón de "Página completa"):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
  var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
});

$(function() {
  $('.nav-center').addClass('tr');
})

$('#sas').on('click', function() {
  console.log('sas precionado');
  $('.nav-center').addClass('fixed-top', 2000, "easeOutBounce");
})
```

```css
.tr {
  transition: top 1s
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.nav-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.nav-center ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

nav.nav-center ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container section">
    <h1>cards</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-tabs">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 1</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test5">Test 2</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test6">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content grey lighten-4">
            <div id="test4">Test 1</div>
            <div id="test5">Test 2</div>
            <div id="test6">Test 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-center">
    <div class="nav-wrapper  indigo darken-4">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#" id="sas">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>


</body>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el `nav` no tiene posicionamiento inicial, entonces cuando le das la clase "fixedTop" y se cambia a `position:fixed` con un valor en el `top` salta porque inicialmente no tenía ningún valor por lo que no hay una transición válida que hacer.

Aparte de eso, la manera en la que estás cambiando la clase es una combinación entre [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) y `animate`, que funciona para cambiar la clase, pero no es correcta y no va a animar la transición como esperas.

Una opción para resolver esto sería darle un posicionamiento al hacer click y entonces cambiar la clase (como estarías poniendo los estilos inline, hay que poner un `!important` en el `top` de `.fixed-top`, lo cual no es ideal... aunque funciona).

Pero hay que hacerlo de una manera un poco especial, porque si cambias los estilos y automáticamente cambias la clase, al navegador no le habrá dado tiempo a "refrescar" el elemento. Entonces tiene que haber una pequeña pausa (si no recuerdo mal, es alrededor de 16ms) entre una acción y la otra.

Podrías hacerlo con un `setTimeout` pero vamos a hacerlo con algo que se ve más *elegante*: usando las funciones [`.when()` y `.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) de jQuery. El contenido del `then` no se ejecutará hasta que no haya terminado la ejecución del contenido del `when`.

Aparte de eso, para calcular la posición del elemento en la pantalla puedes usar el método [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) de jQuery (calculando un poco dependiendo del alto de la ventana).

Al final la función quedaría así:

```
$('#sas').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('sas precionado');
  // calculamos la posición desde el alto de la pantalla
  const offsetTop = $('.nav-center').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  // cuando 
  $.when(
    // se cambien los estilos del navbar
    $('.nav-center').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: `${offsetTop}px`
    })
  // entonces
  ).then(
    // añadiremos la clase
    function() {
      $('.nav-center').addClass('fixed-top');
    }
  );
})
```

Y aquí puedes ver la función dentro de tu código:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
  var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
});

$(function() {
  $('.nav-center').addClass('tr');
})

$('#sas').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('sas precionado');
  const offsetTop = $('.nav-center').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  $.when(
    $('.nav-center').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: `${offsetTop}px`
    })
  ).then(
    function() {
      $('.nav-center').addClass('fixed-top');
    }
  );
})
```

```css
.tr {
  transition: top 1s
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0 !important; /* fijate que añadí !important aquí */
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.nav-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.nav-center ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

nav.nav-center ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container section">
    <h1>cards</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-tabs">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 1</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test5">Test 2</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test6">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content grey lighten-4">
            <div id="test4">Test 1</div>
            <div id="test5">Test 2</div>
            <div id="test6">Test 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-center">
    <div class="nav-wrapper  indigo darken-4">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#" id="sas">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>


</body>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

---

Alternativamente, para evitar el `when...then` (que puede ser algo inconsistente porque aún podría ejecutarse antes de que se hayan aplicado los estilos) en lugar de cambiar de clase, lo que podrías hacer es animar el navbar una vez le hayas dado los estilos.

Algo como esto (fíjate que he comentado la transición de CSS para que no cause problemas con el `animate` de jQuery):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
  var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
});

$(function() {
  $('.nav-center').addClass('tr');
})

$('#sas').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('sas precionado');
  const offsetTop = $('.nav-center').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

  $('.nav-center').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: `${offsetTop}px`
  })

  $('.nav-center').animate({ top: 0 }, 2000);

})
```

```css
.tr {
  /* transition: top 1s */
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.nav-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.nav-center ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

nav.nav-center ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container section">
    <h1>cards</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-tabs">
            <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width">
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 1</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test5">Test 2</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a href="#test6">Test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content grey lighten-4">
            <div id="test4">Test 1</div>
            <div id="test5">Test 2</div>
            <div id="test6">Test 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav-center">
    <div class="nav-wrapper  indigo darken-4">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="center hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#" id="sas">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>


</body>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</html>
```